# What's the difference and the meaning of 地震がある場合には and 地震の場合には

Tags: grammar

I came across the following grammar rule about the use of 場合

> N+の場合（には）:
> 地震の場合には、エレベーターは使用禁止。

> V〜た＋場合:
> 遅れた場合には、会議に入れません。

> V〜辞書形＋場合:
> 遅れる場合には、・・・。

It seems to me that when it comes to natural disasters Japanese prefers N+場合 instead of 地震がある場合には・・・ or 地震があった場合には・・・ for instance.

Therefore, could anyone explain to me whether the following sentences are grammatically correct, and their meaning and differences?

> 1. 地震がある／起きる場合には、電話してください。
> 2. 地震があった／起きた場合には、電話してください。
> 3. 地震の場合には、電話してください。

Answer (score 1):

To follow the first instruction 「地震があ**る**／起き**る**場合には、電話してください」, you would need to know in advance that an earthquake will happen and make a phone call before it strikes, which probably requires some kind of supernatural power.

「津波が来る場合には、電話してください」 may be a valid instruction, though, because a tsunami follows an earthquake with a delay and you may have time to prepare for it before it arrives.

In terms of timing, the other two basically mean the same thing. You would make a phone call after an earthquake has occurred.

This is related: [The use of present and past tenses in ～時 sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30877/43676)

Comment: なぜにダウンボートされてんですかこれ

Comment: @Chocolate - さあ、分かりません。

Answer (score -1):

They more or less mean the same. There is a slight nuance which doesn't change the meaning between ある and あった (note that it's not the past tense).

1. When an earthquake occurs, call me.
2. When an earthquake occurs, call me.
3. In case of an earthquake, call me.

Comment: 地震がある場合には電話してください <- 地震予知能力がないと無理ですねー (＾▽＾)

Comment: @Chocolate 問題がある場合には連絡くださいとも正しくないってことですか。

Comment: 「問題がある場合には」はおかしくないですね。「地震がある場合は～」がおかしいのは、「事故が起こる場合は連絡してください」「事故にあう場合は連絡してください」がおかしいのと同じかな？

Comment: なるほど。私には区別がつかないので信じておきます。

Comment: 「問題がある」は状態だからです。一方、「地震がある」や「事故が起こる」は瞬間的な変化を指します。辞書形で使うと、これから起こることとして解釈されます。

Comment: @oldergod You are not wrong at all. You are just insightful than the average Joe. The following sentence is valid: "地震を減らすために○○を実施しました。（それでも今後）地震が起きる場合には電話してください". It's a typical "We implemented the solution but if the problem persists let us know" phrase. Although such technology is probably unavailable today, availability/lack of a technology shouldn't dictate the validity of grammar. The context and "common sense" may influence its lexical aspect though.